# Concat two arrays with filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, lodash

I have two arrays. I need to combine both of them and make a new array which has `dayOfWeek` 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Which means priority for the `dayOfWeek` is in `array1`. Means need to keep `dayOfWeek` 3, 4, 5 from `array1`.

```
array1 = [
  {dayOfWeek: 2, home1: "01:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "02:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "03:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "04:30"},
]

array2 = [
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "05:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "06:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "07:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 6, home1: "08:30"},
]
```

Output should be

```
finalArray = [
  {dayOfWeek: 2, home1: "01:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "02:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "03:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "04:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 6, home1: "08:30"},
]
```

I tried this but it pushes the `dayOfWeek` from both the arrays. How can I filter them?

```
const finalArray = []
array1.map((a) => {
    array2.map((a2) => {
        if (a.dayOfWeek === a2.dayOfWeek) {
          finalArray.push(a)
        }
        if (a.dayOfWeek === a2.dayOfWeek) {
          finalArray.push(a2)
        }
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lodash's [`_.unionBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#unionBy). The predominant array should be the 1st array passed to the function.

```js
const array1 = [{"dayOfWeek":2,"home1":"01:30"},{"dayOfWeek":3,"home1":"02:30"},{"dayOfWeek":4,"home1":"03:30"},{"dayOfWeek":5,"home1":"04:30"}]
const array2 = [{"dayOfWeek":3,"home1":"05:30"},{"dayOfWeek":4,"home1":"06:30"},{"dayOfWeek":5,"home1":"07:30"},{"dayOfWeek":6,"home1":"08:30"}]

const result = _.unionBy(array1, array2, 'dayOfWeek')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to combine several properties to use as the union value, you can use:

```
_.unionBy(array1, array2, o => `${o.id}-${o.dayOfWeek}`)
```

Comment: Can I use two fields for the `_.unionBy` . I need to union by `dayOfWeek` and `id`?

Comment: See addition to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply filter the second array for the items missing form the first and then concatenate those to the first array without lodash:

```js
const a1 = [ {dayOfWeek: 2, home1: "01:30"}, {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "02:30"}, {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "03:30"}, {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "04:30"}, ]
const a2 = [ {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "05:30"}, {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "06:30"}, {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "07:30"}, {dayOfWeek: 6, home1: "08:30"}, ]

const r = a1.concat(a2.filter(x => !a1.some(y => y.dayOfWeek == x.dayOfWeek)))

console.log(r)
```

This is done via `Array.concat`, `Array.filter` and `Array.some`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Set` and `Array.filter`

```js
let array1 = [
  {dayOfWeek: 2, home1: "01:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "02:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "03:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "04:30"},
]

let array2 = [
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "05:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "06:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "07:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 6, home1: "08:30"},
]

let s = new Set()
console.log([...array1, ...array2].filter(d => {
    let avail = s.has(d.dayOfWeek)
    !avail && s.add(d.dayOfWeek)
    return !avail
  }
) )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use array concatenation method and after that do filter.

```
var c = array1.concat(array2);
```

Comment: sorry but I don't want to concat. BTW Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Profer. You could use Map object to get unique elements

```
const array1 = [
  {dayOfWeek: 2, home1: "01:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "02:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "03:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "04:30"},
];

const array2 = [
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "05:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "06:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "07:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 6, home1: "08:30"},
];

function getFinalArray(array, uniqueProperty) {
  return array
    .filter(value => value)
    .reduce(
      (arrayMap, item) => {
        return arrayMap.set(item[uniqueProperty], item)
      }, new Map()
    );
}

const result = Array.from(
  getFinalArray([...array2, ...array1], 'dayOfWeek').values()
);
```

Comment: If you don't want the order to get mangled you could do: `.reduce(
      (arrayMap, item) =>
        !arrayMap.get(item[uniqueProperty])
          ? arrayMap.set(item[uniqueProperty], item)
          : arrayMap,
      new Map(),` pass in the arrays as [...array1,...array2]`

Comment: Thanks for the addition.
it could be nice to **do check** this way `arrayMap.has(item[uniqueProperty])` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) methods:

- Use `.slice(0)` to get all elements of `array1` in `finalArray`.
- Then use `.forEach()` to iterate over `array2` and get all elements that doesn't exist  in `finalArray`.
- Use `.some()` to check if the iterated element (`dayOfWeek`) exist.

This is how should be your code:

```
var finalArray = array1.slice(0);
array2.forEach(function(a){
      if(!finalArray.some(e => e.dayOfWeek == a.dayOfWeek))
          finalArray.push(a);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
let array1 = [
  {dayOfWeek: 2, home1: "01:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "02:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "03:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "04:30"},
];

let array2 = [
  {dayOfWeek: 3, home1: "05:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 4, home1: "06:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 5, home1: "07:30"},
  {dayOfWeek: 6, home1: "08:30"},
];

var finalArray = array1.slice(0);
array2.forEach(function(a){
      if(!finalArray.some(e => e.dayOfWeek == a.dayOfWeek))
          finalArray.push(a);
});

console.log(finalArray);
```